# event.preventDefualt() not working in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason the event.preventDefualt() is not working when I switched the file from .php to .html. I have tried binding the form by using .bind(), .live(), .on() and none seem to work. I have also tried to 'return false' instead of the event.preventDefualt() function I really am at a loss here.

Jquery

```
// variable to hold request
    var request;
    // bind to the submit event of our form
    $("#getBooksByName").submit(function(event){
        // abort any pending request
        if (request) {
            request.abort();
        }
        // setup some local variables
        var $form = $(this);

        // let's select and cache all the fields
        var $inputs = $form.find("input");

        // serialize the data in the form
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();
        // let's disable the inputs for the duration of the ajax request
        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

        var splitSerialized = serializedData.split('=');
        console.log(splitSerialized);
        // fire off the request to /form.php
        request = $.ajax({
            url: "http://192.168.0.140/ereader-backend/public/books/search/",
            type: "GET",
            data: splitSerialized,
            success: function(returned) {
                $("#clear-name").val($("#clear-name").attr('placeholder'));
                if(jquery.isEmptyObject(returned) != true){

                    var result = '';
                    result += '<h3 class="headers book-title-two">Search results for : '+splitSerialized+'</h3>';
                    $.each(returned, function(i, item) {
                        result += '<div class="medium-3 small-6 columns left books-spacing">';
                        result += '<a href="book.php?id='+item.id+'">';
                        result += '<div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns" style="min-height:230px">';
                        if(item.image != ''){
                            result += '<img src="uploaded/covers/'+item.image+'" alt="'+item.name+'" />';
                        }
                        else{
                            result += '<img src="uploaded/no-available-image.png" alt="'+item.name+'" class="not-available" />';
                        }
                        result += '</div>';
                        result += '<div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns">';
                        result += '<h5 class="book-title-two">'+item.name+'</h5>'
                        result += '</div>';
                        result += '</a>';
                        result += '</div>';
                    });
                }
                else{
                    result += '<h3 class="book-title-two">No results for: '+splitSerialized+'</h3>';
                }
                $("div#all_books").html(result);

            }
        });

        // callback handler that will be called on success
        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            // log a message to the console
        });

        // callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // log the error to the console
        });

        // callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {
            // reenable the inputs
            $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
        });

        // prevent default posting of form
        event.preventDefault();

    });
```

HTML

```
<form id="getBooksByName" name="getBooksByName" method="POST">
    <div class="medium-8 small-8 columns no-padding">
    <input type="text" id="clear-name" name="search" placeholder="Search book">
</div>
<div class="medium-4 small-4 columns no-padding">
    <input type="submit" class="medium small button search" value=""/>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: it's `preventDefault()`  (see http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) ...

Comment: As @Brice said, you have a typo in your function call to preventDefault (you've missplaced the a and u in Default).

Comment: that was a spelling mistake sorry on my part. Still doesnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

instead of:

```
event.preventDefualt();
```

Comment: whats different between first `event.preventDefault();` with second `event.preventDefualt();` ???

Comment: The position of letter `a` and `u` inside `Default`

Comment: It was a typo but with the correctly written function it still does not work :/